# Store unique download requests in database

Tags: php

I'm trying to get some client information and store each download file request in database. After storing all needed information, download request is being processed:

```
return response()->download($file_path);
```

The problem is that on each request, mostly by download managers, many connections are made to the same URL so application stores multiple rows on the same request by user.

I want to limit this storing on per unique client request not per connection. I thought preventing multiple connections will do it for me, so I added `Accept-Ranges` header:

```
return response()->download($file_path, null, ["Accept-Ranges" => "None"]);
```

Although downloads are not resume-able anymore, multiple rows are stored in database. (However it's much less than before)

What would be the best practice to avoid multiple database insertions on a user download request?

** Please do not answer or comment without considering that **multiple duplicate and simultaneous** requests differ from **multiple unique and simultaneous** requests. Otherwise there are plenty of solutions out there.*

*P.S. I don't want to tag my question with Laravel. Please do not add it.*

Comment: You can give each download a unique id, which will be visible in the url and which will be expired at some times. So as long as the download is resumed using that id, you can consider it the same download. Although you must take care whether to expire the link or not when the last range of that file has been sent. This is just an opinion.

Comment: I think it's not considered as a good practice. You may miss unique download requests because you don't have any idea about that key's expiration time and maybe someone tries to download a file more than once in that particular period. @frz3993

Comment: Have you tried checking `Range` header values before the insertion into the database? For the new/unique download request, it should not be presented or start from 0.

Comment: Why don't you implement a one download per user per x hours/days per specific file. There is no reason for a user to download the same file more than 1 time unless the download was corrupt or stopped downloading?

Comment: @max Would you post your comment as an answer? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried checking `Range` header values before the insertion into the database?

For the new/unique download request, it should not be presented or start from 0.

Answer (score 0):

For Understanding unique users, you need authentication system. But I see you are not able to use authentication system.

There isn't any absolute way to do this. Users can change ip address, delete or change cookies etc., because everything is on their hand.

Still you can insert **ip, http_user_agent** to database and also to increase quality you can set some **cookie** to identify unique user.

Also, you can use [PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) - for user management system.

```
session_start();
$id = session_id();
```

Check current session user. If already download request is there of same user then update request, if not create one.

**Update:**

If you are using sessions and authentication as per your comment then store when download request comes:

```
+----+---------+---------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| id | user_id | file_id | status      | created_at      | updated_at      |
+----+---------+---------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 1  | 1       | 1       | in_progress | 1456477761.9624 | 1456477762.9624 |
+----+---------+---------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

When authenticated user requests to download specific file, add row in DB specifying it's status. Whenever any new request to download file comes, you will check status with that user and file requested. If record present then you will not allow user to download file.

Comment: How storing user's IP address and user agent can lead to finding out unique requests? Also users are authenticated before sending a download request. That's why I need some information about their download requests.

Comment: So why can't you use sessions to identify download requests then?

Comment: Using sessions how can we track unique download requests? Isn't it possible for current user to send another download request to the same file while he is downloading it? If yes then how sessions should be implemented to recognize the difference that will result in storing only 2 rows in database?

Comment: Regarding to your last edit: Actually, **I want** to store all download requests even though a download request is already stored in DB and it is progressing (as you said its status is `in_progress`). But which **I don't want** is to not add/update a record of the same download request (an `in_progress` download) which is caused by multiple connections made to the same file URL.

Comment: @revo: As per my thinking, you can also use `id` of downloads table for file with status. Until same file is getting downloaded you can use `id` to resume download. After completing download, you can change status to `completed`. I am confused about your requirements. Can you explain in details what you want happen and what not?

Comment: I think you are confused because you couldn't distinguish between **multiple duplicate and simultaneous requests** and **multiple unique and simultaneous requests** by one user.

Answer (score 0):

You can try storing the user agent and check with evry request if user agent if same but a user, may try downloading via different browsers / download managers at the same time so not full proof .. 
BUT 
Since you have mentioned in the question that you are not supporting / allowing users to resume the downloads .. 
Hence after the user has started the download he may try downloading via different browsers but the possibility of user ip adress getting changed is very less ...
So you can store user browsr agent + user ip adress and check with every request if they are the same before making a new entry in your database .. 
This may not be 100% proof but im guessing your problem will be solved upto a extend !